# Search columns in mysql table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 300+ column. Looking for a specific column is like nightmare. Is there any query where If I would like to search for columns stats with 'grand' can be listed...

Comment: try where clause  (........where column like 'grand%')

Comment: mean column name starts with `grand`?

Comment: yes Ulas, column name starts with grand..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `show columns from table` with `where`. Try the following query,

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename WHERE field like 'grand%';
```

Just put in your tablename after FROM and it would work.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from myTable where mycolumn like 'grand%'
```

Comment: Your query will return the result which starts with `grand` from the column `mycolumn`. OP wants columns which the name of the column starts with `grand`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT 
    table_name, 
    column_name, 
    data_type,
    ordinal_position

FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 

WHERE table_schema = 'DatabaseName'     --- the database you want to search 
  AND table_name = 'yourTableName'
  AND column_name LIKE '%Grand' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me. Its shows all columns and table in entire database

```
  SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE column_name OR table_name LIKE '%sale%';
```